# TYPO3 TCE modify onChange in THEFORM

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have a field (let's call is `select1`) which is used in twoContent Elements. In one of the Content Element it needs to reloads the TCE Form because some fields only need to be shown if `select1` has a certain value selected.

This works fine as I'm using the following TCE:

TCE for the `select1` field:

```
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'foo',
        'onChange' => 'reload',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'default' => 1,
            'items' => [
                [
                    'foo1',
                    1,
                ],
                [
                    'foo2',
                    2,
                ],

            ],
        ],
```

Now the challenge is, that I'm using the same field (select1) in another content element and there I don't need the reload onChange.

I've tried to change the value of the `onChange` within TCEFORM (I've tried it eventhough its the only field that you apparently cant modify through TCE, according to the TCE Docs)

```
TCEFORM {
    tt_content {
        select1{
            types {
                mySecondContentElement{
                    onChange = ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to disable the onChange for a ceratin Content Element?

I could create a new Field in the Database, but this seems wrong to me.

I'm using TYPO3 LTS 11.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TsConfig only some specific columns can be overriden and not all but you can use the feature `columnsOverrides` which is described [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Types/Properties/ColumnsOverrides.html#columnsoverrides)

So that could look like that

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['your-ce-type']['columnsOverrides']['select1']['onChange'] = 'reload'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked. I've changed your code snippet since the onChange is no in the conifg sub array. Just in case someone needs this code.

Comment: approved the change, thanks!